# MySQL trigger BEFORE INSERT with INSERT and SIGNAL won't work

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_backup` (
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER `dousers` BEFORE INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF LOWER(NEW.user_email) LIKE '%@test.pl' THEN
     INSERT INTO tbl_backup (`user_email`) VALUES (NEW.user_email);
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'Strange error!';
END IF;

END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Trigger work, but only in half way. when  the condition is fulfilled then I got error (this one defined in trigger `Strange error!`) but `INSERT INTO tbl_backup` doesn't work. I don't have new records in `tbl_backup` table. If I remove `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` from trigger then when the condition is fulfilled I see new records in `tbl_backup`. I also test this trigger with older MySQL 5.1 with `call some_non_exist_function` and it works like a charm. I'm doing something wrong or in MySQL 5.5 I can't use `INSERT` and `SIGNAL` in single trigger?
MySQL ver 5.5.45

Comment: What doesn't work. We can't read your mind or debug for you.

Comment: @Drew `INSERT INTO tbl_backup (`user_email`) VALUES (NEW.user_email);` doesn't work if after is `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'Strange error!';` if I remove line with `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` then `INSERT` work

Comment: I can fool around with it in 6 to 8 hours from now. Can ask another guy I know that does signals to look too. If you could document with an [edit] a url link to a sqlfiddle for table creation, that would be great.

Comment: @Drew I write question once again, but unfortunatly on this browser I can't use sqlfiddle

Comment: See answer in [Unable to use SIGNAL and INSERT at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062106/unable-to-use-signal-and-insert-at-the-same-time).

Comment: @wchiquito thanks you so much `ALTER TABLE \`tbl_backup\` ENGINE=MyISAM;` and trigger works perfect

Comment: @wchiquito yeah here is the question, and you found it anyway. You were "the guy" I was referring to but weren't online at the time :p